# Convert Tif image to byte[]

Tags: java, file-io, bufferedimage, javax.imageio

I tried to convert Tiff image to Byte[] but **getting exception from java 1.8 sdk**. I searched in google but did not get solution yet. **Same code works for java 1.6**.

```
public static byte[] convertImage(String dirName, String imageName)
{
    try
    {
    //String dirName="C:\\Temp\\";
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos=new ByteArrayOutputStream(1000);
    BufferedImage img=ImageIO.read(new File(dirName,imageName));

    ImageIO.write(img, "tif", baos);
    baos.flush();

    byte[] bytearray = baos.toByteArray();

    baos.close();

    return bytearray;
    }
    catch(IOException ioe)
    {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;

}
```

variable **img** is always null in java 1.8 but 1.6 returns info.

Exception raised from sdk 1.8 as follows

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: image == null!
at javax.imageio.ImageTypeSpecifier.createFromRenderedImage(Unknown Source)
at javax.imageio.ImageIO.getWriter(Unknown Source)
at javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(Unknown Source)
at test.practice.net.ConverterImageUsing18.convertImage(ConverterImageUsing18.java:88)
at test.practice.net.ConverterImageUsing18.GetBase64BinaryAsString(ConverterImageUsing18.java:52)
at test.practice.net.ConverterImageUsing18.main(ConverterImageUsing18.java:42)
```

Any hits or sample code is appreciable.

Comment: if you know this is failing` BufferedImage img=ImageIO.read(new File(dirName,imageName));` why are you bothering any further. Debug this. You must be swallowing and exception somewhere.

Comment: @Shahzeb No, `ImageIO.read(..)` simply returns `null` for a file type it does not recognize. See my answer below for further details.

Comment: Yes, TIFF is optional, maybe "tiff"?

Answer (score 4):

ImageIO needs an additional plugin to read or write TIFF. The [built-in formats](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/package-summary.html#package_description) are BMP, GIF, JPEG, PNG and WBMP. To read or write TIFF, you can use JAI (`jai_imageio.jar`), [TwelveMonkeys ImageIO](http://haraldk.github.io/TwelveMonkeys/) or similar.

Without a suitable plugin, `ImageIO.read(...)` simply returns `null`. This is the most likely reason why your `img` is `null` (and you get an exception). You might have JAI or similar installed in your Java 1.6 JRE, or you may be testing with a different file.

However, if you just want to get the bytes of the original file, there's no need to use ImageIO at all. Simply read the bytes from the file into a byte array, for example like this:

```
File file = new File(dirName, imageName);
int length = (int) file.length();
byte[] bytes = new byte[length];

try (DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(file))) {
    input.readFully(bytes);
}
```

Or in Java 8, you can write it more elegant (thanks, @JoopEggen):

```
File file = new File(dirName, imageName);
byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath());
```

Comment: Nowadays `byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath());`, but good suggestion.

Comment: Thanks for information. But the above code returns byte [] with all 0's value. i.e. [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,.....]. I think value should not be all 0's. After that i tried to convert this byte array to base64binary string using DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary() method and  returns "AAAAA ....." value which is not okay. Do you have any other solution? I have not tried using JAI yet. I will try to convert Tif image using JAI.

Comment: @Morshed No, it should only contain all `0`s if the original file contains all `0`s. Are you sure you got the correct code? The above code works for me. Looks to me like you left some of the code out (the `readFully(bytes)` part). PS: Changed the code slightly, to look better for Java < 8. But it works just the same.